# Is it possible to copy an entire hdf5 file and expanding external links with h5copy?

Tags: hdf5

I have an HDF5 file with external links and would like to copy the file to one single file, so that there are no more external links.

Is there a way to do this with h5copy?

I tried with

```
h5copy --source "/" --destination "/" --flag ext \
       --input celldemo.ims --output output/celldemo_copied.ims
```

But I get the error:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.17) thread 140735996208000:
  #000: H5Ocopy.c line 248 in H5Ocopy(): destination object already exists
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object already exists
Error in copy...Exiting
```

File details:

```
File: celldemo.ims
Groups:
  DataSet
  DataSetInfo
  Thumbnail
```

Properties of groups (as displayed in the HDFView tool):

```
DataSet
  Link To Target: subfolder/dataset.ims://DataSet
  Type: HDF5 Group
(same for DataSetInfo and Thumbnail)
```

Why do I get this error? Is the "/" an invalid source and destination object name?